# Big difference of accuracy between C-SVC and nu-SVC using SVM

Tags: r, classification, svm, image-processing, overfitting

I'm currently dealing with an image classification problems.
The objective is to classify the images to 4 classes, with 8000 images in the training set and 14000 images to predict.

I'm using the SVM implemented in the kernlab package in R, and there is a huge difference on accuracy between C-SVC and nu-SVC.
The kernel is rbf, and I'm using all the default parameters.

Using a 5-fold cross validation, the cross validation error for C-SVC is as high as 49%, and for nu-SVC it's 27%.
What's even more strange is that the training error(no cross validation) of C-SVC is always around 56%, but for nu-SVC it can go down as low as 5%.

**So what's strange is:**

Why the training error of C-SVC can bi higher than it's cross validation error rate?

Why the error rate of C-SVC can be so much higher than that of nu-SVC? (it seems that adjusting parameters of C-SVC doesn't help much) And besides, C-SVC and nu-SVC seems to be the same thing mathematically?

**EDIT 1**

I've changed from doing a 4-class classification to doing four 0-1 classification problems, and C-SVC works well. The error rates are almost the same as those of nu-SVC.

So maybe the problem has something to do with overfitting and multi-level classification?

Comment: Did you tune `nu` and `C`? `nu` is an upper bound for training error.

Comment: Yes, tuning 'C' and 'sigma' for rbf doesn't change much, it's always bad for C-SVC. and the default value `nu=0.2` already performs well

Comment: Which range did you use to tune `C`? `C` $\in (0,+\infty]$

Comment: I used about [0.001,1000] to tune `C`

Comment: What is the value of $\rho$ you get with $\nu$-SVC? Setting $C = \frac{1}{\rho}$ should be equivalent for $C$-SVC (depending on the scaling they use when solving; sometimes you may need to scale by $n$, the number of data points)